# How to mirror all tags from a container to another one registry or namespace?

Tags: containers, mirror

I want perform a mirror/sync by copying all container tags from a registry and pushing it under a different name, to the same registry or another one.

I can make use of either docker or podman. While podman can perform a `podman pull --all-tags ...` it does not have an option for pushing all tags.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an imagesync [tool](https://github.com/MQasimSarfraz/imagesync) to automate syncing of all the tags across different registries:

```
docker run --rm -it smqasims/imagesync:v1.0.0 --src SRC_REGISTRY_HOST/<REPOSITORY> --dest DEST_REGISTRY_HOST/<REPOSITORY
```

e.g (private registries):

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${HOME}/.docker/config.json:/root/.docker/config.json smqasims/imagesync:v1.0.0 --src docker.io/smqasims/foo --dest docker.io/smqasims/bar
```

This will sync both the repositories and is faster/manageable manner.